# how to solve Flutter RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: android, flutter

I am working with Flutter and I am trying to show Admob Banner at the top of body before GridView Widget
The problem is when advertisement is loaded it make the following issue

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

I am sure it's only UI issue because if I run the app with only widget (admob or gridview) it works perfectly but when add both I have the issue

here is my code

```
 return SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  _isBannerAdReady
                      ? AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd)
                      : Text("no Ads"),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: examsList.length,
                        gridDelegate:
                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    examsList[index].image!!,
                                    width: 150,
                                    height: 150,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Text(examsList[index].name!!))
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ));
```

Comment: you didn't share your adWidget code. but I think it's because adWidget(ad:...) has no width and height. try to wrap it with a Container(width: double.infinity,height:50)

Comment: yes it works thank you verymuch

Comment: So I put that as an answer for other who curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because adWidget(ad:...) has no width and height. try to wrap it with a `Container(width: double.infinity,height:50)`